# Angularjs addmore directive and scope management

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am trying to create a directive which has addmore button.

In the controller I have a `tickets` obj which is empty. I am trying to add new tickets (multiple) to this obj while clicking "Add Tickets".

What I need is

- Each ticket should increment by 1.
- The ticket `price` should be updated in `tickets` array when a `price` is
  updated in input box (two way binding).
- Should be able to update the `quantity` from controller or directive
  which should update in quantity input (one way binding).

I have created a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/IsrgI7GCSCCs4gQAP8mk?p=preview) , any help would be appreciated, have spend lot of time in this.

Comment: Is there a reason to prefer directive over component(s) ?

Comment: I posted you a components version, let me know if you want a directive(s) version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Fancy solution  with components

I forked your plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/xFy16oo5SVLyCArU6zPN?p=preview) with a component version.

When you can, I recommand you the use of components over directives.

I splitted it in two components, that's way easier to separate the functionnalities. One components for the list, and an other for one item representation.

### tickets component

It handles the ng-repeat on components, the add button and the sum functions.

```
app.component('tickets', {
  template: '<div ng-repeat="ticket in $ctrl.tickets">#{{ticket.id}}<ticket ng-change="$ctrl.recompute()" assign="$ctrl.assign" ng-model="ticket"/></div><hr><button ng-click="$ctrl.addOne()">Add One</button><br>Total price : {{$ctrl.price}}<br>Total quantity : {{$ctrl.quantities}}',
  controller: class Ctrl {
    $onInit() {
      this.tickets = [];
      this.price = 0;
      this.quantities = 0;
    }

    count() {
      return this.tickets.length;
    }

    addOne() {
      this.tickets.push({
        id: this.count(),
        price: 0,
        color: 'red',
        quantity: 1
      });
      this.recompute();
    }

    recompute() {
      this.price = 0;
      this.quantities = 0;
      this.tickets.forEach((ticket) => {
        this.price += ticket.price;
        this.quantities += ticket.quantity;
      });
    }

    assign(ticket) {
      console.log("ticket Assigned : ", ticket);
    }
  }
});
```

### ticket component

It handles the representation and actions for **one** ticket.

```
app.component('ticket', {
  template: '<div><label>Quantity</label><input type="number" ng-model="$ctrl.ticket.quantity" ng-change="$ctrl.ngChange"/><br><label>Price</label><input type="number" ng-model="$ctrl.ticket.price" ng-change="$ctrl.ngChange"/><br><button ng-click="$ctrl.assignMe()">Assign</button></div>',
  bindings: {
    ngModel: '=',
    ngChange: '<',
    assign: '<'
  },
  controller: class Ctrl {
    $onInit() {
      this.ticket = this.ngModel;
    }

    assignMe() {
      this.assign(this.ticket);
    }

    addOne() {
      this.tickets.push({
        price: 0,
        color: 'red',
        quentity: 0
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Let me now if you want a version with directive.